# Edit a file of questions and answers with perl and html

Tags: html, perl

I am trying to write a perl script which allows the editing of a separate file of questions and answers. I can't seem to figure out something that seems to work well without writing ridiculous looking, inefficient code.

I want it to be able to add completely new questions/answers to the file, as well as edit already existing questions/answers. Any advice on how to make this work?

EDIT: Say I have a textarea. Can I make a button that deletes the text entered in the textarea from the related file? A textarea that, when you enter in a question, you can choose to press the "delete" button, and, if that question exists inside of the .txt file, remove it from the file?

This is the script:

```
if($newquestion != $oldquestion and $newanswer != $oldanswer) {
            print $ANS "$newquestion\t$newanswer\n";
        } else {
            if($newquestion != $oldquestion and $newanswer == $oldanswer) {
                print $ANS "$newquestion\t$newanswer\n";
            } elsif($newquestion == $oldquestion and $newanswer != $oldanswer) {
                print $ANS "$oldquestion\t$newquestion\n";
            }   
        }
    }
```

This is the html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Edit Questions and Answers!<br><br>
        Type the question in the first area, and the answer to it in the other<br>
        ~answerlist~<br><br>
        <form action="viewquestions.dhtml" method="post">
            Questions and Answers:<br>
            <textarea rows="1" cols="25" name="newquestion">Question
            </textarea>
            <textarea rows="1" cols="25" name="newanswer">Answer
            </textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="site" value="~site~"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="xs" value="~xs~"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="username" value="~username~"/>
        </form>
        <a href="/client_homepage.dhtml~useridtext~&frompage=View and Answer Questions">Return to home page</a><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have existing HTML files which you can add to or create if its a new question and serve up the whole thing if requested? A bit like stackoverflow? You might want to consider saving your files in XML as there are many packages for dealing with XML. You can then transform it to HTML using an XSLT package.

Comment: If you are comparing strings, you must use `eq` and `ne`.  `==` and `!=` are for comparing numerics.

Answer (score 0):

You produce that bad code because you lack the fundamentals, [get a book or two about beginner Web programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books).

You put your questions/answer into a database instead of a text file. This guarantees that updates are not lost when several concurrent datasets are written.

```
echo 'create table qa(id integer primary key autoincrement, question text, answer text);' | sqlite3 qa.sqlite
```

Access the database with an ORM for convenience (lines 3-5). Your Web application calls for a single-page "monkey form":

```
use 5.010;
use strictures;
use DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader qw();
DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader->naming({ALL => 'preserve'});
my $table = DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader->connect('dbi:SQLite:dbname=qa.sqlite')->resultset('Qa');

use Text::Xslate qw();
my $tt = Text::Xslate->new(syntax => 'TTerse');
my $template = <<'';
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Edit Questions and Answers!</title>
        <style>
            textarea { width: 25em; height: 1em; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>existing questions and answers</h1>
        [% FOR pair IN qa %]
        <form action="[% action %]" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="[% pair.id %]" />
            <textarea name="question">[% pair.question %]</textarea>
            <textarea name="answer">[% pair.answer %]</textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="update" value="update" />
            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" />
        </form>
        [% END %]
        <h1>new question and answer</h1>
        <form action="[% action %]" method="POST">
            <label for="question">Question:</label>
            <textarea name="question" id="question"></textarea>
            <label for="answer">Answer:</label>
            <textarea name="answer"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="create" value="create" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

use Plack::Request qw();
my $app = sub {
    my $req = Plack::Request->new(shift);
    my $op = delete $req->body_parameters->{delete} //
             delete $req->body_parameters->{update} //
             delete $req->body_parameters->{create};
    if ('POST' eq $req->method) {
        if ('delete' eq $op) {
            $table->find($req->body_parameters->{id})->delete;
        } else {
            $table->update_or_create($req->body_parameters->as_hashref);
        }
    }
    return $req->new_response(
        200,
        ['Content-Type' => 'application/xhtml+xml'],
        [$tt->render_string($template, { action => $req->uri, qa => [$table->all] })]
    )->finalize;
};
```

That's the whole code. Run the program with [`plackup`](http://p3rl.org/plackup).